# React - Iterating through state array with no result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose

I'm fetching JSON data from a local express server using mongoosejs to parse mongoDB queries. I'm getting a "title" and "id" from the server, to generate a sidebar of buttons.

But my issue is that I can't seem to iterate through the state array after fetching the data from the server

1. The GET request handler on the server:

```js
exports.sidebar = (req, res) => {
  Note.find({}, "_id title")
  .then(notes => {
    console.log(notes);
    res.send(notes)
  }).catch(err => {
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: err
    })
  })
}
```

2. My react component. in loadData(), i fetch the data from the API. and in loadSidebarElements() I try to iterate through the state array,

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
    
class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleList: [],
      idList: []
    }
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
    this.loadSidebarElements = this.loadSidebarElements.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    let titles = [];
    let ids = [];

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
      mode: "cors"
    };
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/notes/sidebar", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.map(item => {
        titles[titles.length] = String(item.title);
        ids[ids.length] = String(item._id);
      })
    })
    this.setState({
      titleList: titles,
      idList: ids
    })
  }

  loadSidebarElements(){
    console.log(this.state.titleList);

    this.state.titleList.map(item => {
      console.log(item);
    })

    this.state.titleList.forEach(item => console.log(item));

    Object.keys(this.state.titleList).map((key, index) => {
      console.log(this.state.titleList[key]);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar" style={{display: "flex", flexDirection:"column",  alignItems: "center"}}>
        <h1>Sidebar:</h1>
        {this.loadSidebarElements()}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Sidebar;
```

3. The console output in firefox:

**Console log from firefox**
[image: Console log from firefox]

I obviously get the data to the server, but I just can't seem to iterate through it...

Comment: Can you explain what that `map` function does? It looks like it repeatedly assigns titles to a number key but I can't figure out why you'd want to do that. Anyway, regardless, that `setState` needs to be in the same `then` statement as that `map`.

Comment: @Andy Im guessing its the one in the fetching request you're referring to. It just pushes the title and id into an array. Then I set the state array to the new array "titles"

Comment: @Andy Putting the setstate within the .then was the solution. wow. thank you so much. Could you explain why this is the case? Thank you so much by the way!

Comment: Because that whole fetch process is asynchronous, and you can't access data that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Andy Alright, that went over my head. Time to read up on that. Thank you so much again!

Comment: I'll try again :). `fetch` goes to the server, collects the JSON, and converts it to a JS object, but all that takes time. You're trying to `setState` with data that hasn't been through the process. When you include `setState` in the final `then` state you're just ensuring that the data is available. [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is really helpful.

Comment: @Andy Ahhh, that totally makes sense. I will keep that in mind when moving forward, and read up more. Thank you so much, again!